# How to make the first match in a group a different group

Tags: group-by, performance-tuning, redshift, columnstore

I need to group by a certain column and to make the first occurrence into another group.

```
select * from table;
```

| id | currency | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USD | 1 |
| 2 | USD | 2 |
| 3 | EUR | 3 |
| 4 | IL | 4 |
| 5 | EUR | 5 |
| 6 | USD | 6 |

So something like that:

```
select min(id) id, currency, sum(amount)
from table
group by currency, 
         case when min(id)=id then 'first-occurrence' else 'rest' end;
```

| id | currency | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USD | 1 |
| 2 | USD | 8 |
| 3 | EUR | 3 |
| 4 | IL | 4 |
| 5 | EUR | 5 |

Of course the `case` doesn't make much sense. The goal is make it also fast, and if possible not to read the table again as the table is huge.

Answer (score 1):

`RANK` helped me:

```
select min(id) id, currency, sum(amount)
FROM (select id, currency, amount, 
              RANK () OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY currency
                     ORDER BY id 
                   ) a_rank
      from table)
group by currency, 
         case when a_rank=1 then 'first-occurrence' 
                            else 'rest' 
         end;
```